# CircleCI not remembering variable values across runs

Tags: circleci

I don't why it is not working, it seems that CircleCI run this commands on Ubuntu (cimg/base). What I'm trying to do is to assign value to variable and then read it in the different `run`, like so:

```
  - run:
      name: Save var
      command: |
        TEST="val"
        echo 'export TEST="${TEST}"' >> "$BASH_ENV"
  - run:
      name: Read var
      command: |
        source ${BASH_ENV}
        echo ${TEST}
```

...but it echoes empty value, not `val` as expected. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax instead:

```
echo "export TEST=${TEST}" >> "$BASH_ENV"
```

With your current syntax, because of the single quotes, what's being written in `$BASH_ENV` is literally: `export TEST="${TEST}"`. But at the time of interpolating (in the following step), `${TEST}` won't return "val" because it is only scoped to the previous step (i.e, it's not a global environment variable).

Also, you don't need the `source ${BASH_ENV}` in the subsequent step; CircleCI does that automatically.